# json serialize python and mongoengine object mix

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization, mongoengine

`json.dumps(o)` converts a native python object to json
`o.to_json()` converts a [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) object such as [`Document`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document) to json

How do you convert a mixed object?
e.g a python `dict`, with mongoengine objects as its values?

Are there tools for this? Or should I create a custom `JSONEncoder` class?

If I do override the encoder, could I create a decoder that reconstructs also the mongoengine objects?

Answer (score 1):

The following encoder serializes python\mongoengine object mixes

```
import json
from mongoengine.base import BaseDocument

class MongoengineObjectsJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, BaseDocument):
            return o._data
        elif isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

Notes:

- This encoder does not add any signature regarding where the python
  objects end and mongoengine objects begin, so it can't be
  automatically deserialized correctly to python\mongoengine objects,
  but rather it will deserialize to a single python object
- I've also added `datetime` object serialization to ISO 8601 format

Comment: That won't work, the default json encoder cant handle mongo's data types correctly as bson is a supertype of json.  MongoEngine just uses pymongo (see bson.json_utils) for the encoding of individual objects or querysets so you should use that for documents eg: `return json_utils.dumps(o.to_mongo())`

Comment: @Ross - do you mean instead of the specific line `return o._data`?

Comment: @Ross - Assuming yes on the above comment, AFAIK if `default()` returns a `str` instead of a `dict` then later in the decoding the entire object will remain as a string, so maybe you mean `return o.to_mongo()`

Comment: @Ross ping on my questions above :)

Comment: i solved my problem by from bson.json_util import dumps and in the end  return dumps(o)